# multilevel menu in pure-drawer

Tags: css, multi-level

I would like to build a multilevel menu using pure-drawer (a css only side menu). The code included with pure-drawer includes a `<ul class="nav-primary">` but does not have css for hiding/unhiding sublevels. How can I add secondary levels to the menu?